# Insert array to multiple rows in MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql

Array $ids contains:

```
Array ( [0] => 25 [1] => 29 [2] => 30 [3] => 34 )
```

How do I insert each key as a row in column `ID`?

```
ID |
25
29
30
34
```

So far I did this, I don't know if it's possible to stick it in the query though:

```
$x = 0;
while($x < 6) {
echo "values ('" . $follower . "','" . $ids[$x] . "')";
$x++;
}
```

Comment: Where do you stuck? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I'm trying to make a loop that echoes the Values and see if that can be integrated in the query. I don't know if it's possible. I add it in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's as simple as that:

```
foreach ($ids as $k => $v) {
     mysql_query("insert into TABLE_NAME(ID) values($v)");
}
```

and for you second question:

```
foreach ($ids as $k => $v) {
    if($k!=0){
        mysql_query("insert into TABLE_NAME values($v)");
    }
}
```

Comment: this will execute query multiple time, but my solution will executed only once for multiple value..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207628/insert-array-to-multiple-rows-in-mysql-database/8207943#8207943

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($ids as  $id=> $val){
mysql_query("insert into table(id,value) values($id,$val)",$cn);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- you iterate through the array: `foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {`
- on each iteration you create an SQL query `$sql = "INSERT INTO table (id) VALUES ($value)";` - of course you will `mysql_real_escape` the value of `$value` before doing this
- then execute the query: `mysql_query($sql)`

Answer (score 1):

you may use

```
$sql = "";
foreach($ids as  $id=> $val){
if(empty($sql)){
$sql = "insert into table(follower,value) values( $follower,$val)";
}else{
$sql.=",($follower,$val)";
}
}
mysql_query($sql);
```